# SMD identification?

Tags: identification

I am looking for help in my effort to identify a SMD on the circuit board of a key fob. The SMD is the one located on the lower right in the image. The large copper pad on the very bottom right connects to the +3v side of the lithium coin cell in the fob. To the left of the copper pad is the spring loaded connector that connects the circuit to the negative side of the lithium coin cell battery. From my limited knowledge derived from a couple semesters of electronics nearly 40 years ago, I am guessing that it is a diode to protect the circuit from a reverse polarity situation but that is just sheer speculation at this point. I was hoping that someone with a much greater depth of knowledge would impart some of their wisdom to me, if it is glaringly obvious as to what this SMD is.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The tan-colored component with two terminals is a capacitor, connected in parallel with the cell. It's used to "decouple" noise from the circuit from the relatively high source impedance of the typical coin cell.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that is helpful but is there anyway to determine the size of the capacitor? I am guessing not and that I'm sol but I obviously don't know much about the subject. There were no markings on the SMD or on the circuit board. When I took the electronics courses years ago you didn't need a microscope to be able to look at the components.

Comment: You'd have to measure it. SMD ceramic capacitors typically have no markings.

Comment: I think that I probably ruined it by attempting to solder it back on with my nearly 40 year old soldering iron. I made quite a mess and the fob does not work.

Comment: Dave, is there a general range in the size of a capacitor that is used to "decouple" noise from the circuit from the relatively high source impedance of the typical coin cell or is the size dependent  upon the circuit that the coin cell is connected to?

Comment: I would expect to see something in the range of 0.1 uF to 10 uF in that position. Probably on the larger side of that range, given that there's a second set of pads for a smaller device (handling higher frequencies) in parallel with it.

Comment: From what I understand, it can't hurt to have a larger capacitor than what is required. iirc capacitors are polarized so how does one go about determining which end is which with one of these tiny ceramic capacitors? I soldered it back on the way it appeared that it should go but the fob did not work afterwards. I may have cooked it or possibly soldered it on backwards, I don't know.

Comment: What I do know is that these fobs are obscenely expensive to buy and then you have to pay to have them programmed for your vehicle which is why I'm trying to resurrect this one. That and the fact that it was my only functioning fob so I'm stranded at the moment. Thanks for all of your help Dave, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ceramic capacitors are not polarized. It's unlikely that this component had anything to do with the failure of the fob.

Comment: It was working but acting up at the time. I used the remote start to start it but I had to walk up to the car before it worked. I thought that the battery might be getting weak so when I got back home I attempted to change the battery. When I popped the back of the case off it looked as if the fob had been dropped in a mud puddle at one point so I tried to use a qtip and rubbing alcohol to try to clean all of the dirt out. That's when this capacitor got dislodged and it hasn't worked since. The capacitor shouldn't have fallen off like it did. Some corrosion might have contributed to that.

Comment: It's more likely that there were other components affected by the corrosion as well. I assume that the photograph in the question is not your specific board, but rather a generic picture you found somewhere.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is a stock photograph but it is the same fob circuit board. The fob worked up until I knocked the capacitor off. Stupid me, this fob is $188.09 on Amazon and then you have to pay to get it programmed. That is why I am attempting to fix it, it's worth a shot, especially considering that I can't drive the car anywhere to get new fobs programmed so someone will have to come here to do it. All I need to do is figure out the SMD packaging, find it on the internet and get some delivered here for another attempted repair.

Comment: I removed the capacitor and it measures 11.2 uF which would be roughly within tolerance if it were a 10% 10 uF capacitor so I didn't destroy it trying to solder it back on. The circuit board and the components look much better since I cleaned it with rubbing alcohol but the fob appears to be quite dead. I am rather baffled as to what happened and why it doesn't work.